# abi.encodePacked() + arrays trick

Tags: solidity, arrays, abiencoderv2

So, I'm realizing that solidity does not allow you to use abi.encodePacked on arrays. I want to be able to return a 2 dimensional uint array printed out and concatenated with other strings. I'm trying to do this with metadata for an NFT. Does anyone know any tricks?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share an example data of what you are trying to do?

Comment: for sure, something like this:


 `string internal svgStart = '<svg.......'
string internal svgEnd = '.....</svg>'


function getSvg(uint[2][] memory list) public view returns (string memory) {
    return string(abi.encodePacked(svgStart, list, svgEnd));
}
`

Comment: I thought it would format better... let me know if it doesnt make sense

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function concat(string[] calldata words) external pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory output;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            output = abi.encodePacked(output, words[i]);
        }

        return string(output);
    }
}
```